# Discord.py воспроизвести музыку от конкретного момента времени

Tags: python, discord.py, mp3

Как написано в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel), воспроизведение аудиофайлов выполняется с помощью метода `VoiceClient.play(source)`

Как можно сделать воспроизведение аудио-файла от конкретной временной точки?

Мне это нужно для реализации бегунка перемотки времени, как в обычных музыкальных программах

Пока что я сделал это через динамическое обрезание аудио-файла во временный файл:

```
from ffmpeg import AudioSegment
import discord

# - наступает момент, когда нужно воспроизвести не с начала:

client.voice_clients[0].stop()

end = full_duration # - полная длительность аудио-файла (в мс)
start = start_position # - позиция, с которой хочу начать воспроизведение (в мс)
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3('initial\file\path\initial-file.mp3') # загружаем изначальный файл для обрезки
extract = song[start:end] # - обрезаем
extract.export('./source.mp3') # - сохраняем

client.voice_clients[0].play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('./source.mp3')) # - воспроизводим обрезанный файл
```

Однако такой способ наверняка не единственный, а так же он очень затратный - если аудио-файл большой, обработка будет очень долгой

Как еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) в [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206503/python-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-mp3-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-bytesio-seek/1206547#1206547)

Позицию надо устанавливать как опцию к CLI-инструментарию `ffmpeg` в параметре `options` или `before_options`, когда создаем класс `FFmpegPCMAudio`

Пример:

```
start_position = 5000 # - пусть надо начать с 5 сек (5000 мсек)
FFmpegPCMAudio(b.read(), pipe=True, options=f"-ss {start_point / 1000}") # - для BytesIO

FFmpegPCMAudio('my_song.mp3', options=f"-ss {start_point / 1000}")
```

Для больших файлов, конечно, подвисает, но уже гораздо лучше и быстрее