# python перемещение по mp3 с помощью BytesIO.seek

Tags: python, discord, io, mp3, bytearray

Загружаю в `io.BytesIO` mp3-файл, и из этого `io.BytesIO` потом его проигрываю

Если его надо проиграть не с начала, а с определенного момента времени, я так понимаю, надо воспользоваться методом `seek`

```
import io

b = io.BytesIO(open('my_song.mp3', 'rb').read())
start_point = 5000 # - время от которого надо начать в миллисекундах

b.seek(convert(start_point, *other_args))

cool_player.play(b.read())
```

Какой вот принцип расчета, который надо реализовать внутри `convert(...)`?

UPD

Проигрываю я эту штуку в голосовой канал discord с помощью [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voice)

```
b = io.BytesIO(open('my_song.mp3', 'rb').read())
start_point = 5000 # - время от которого надо начать в миллисекундах

b.seek(convert(start_point, *other_args))
client.voice_clients[0].play(fixes.FFmpegPCMAudio(b.read(), pipe=True))
```

Причем предоставляемое api выдает ошибку для класса `FFmpegPCAudio`, поэтому я использую пофикшенный вариант [вот отсюда](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5192)

Comment: А как же теги mp3? Вы и их проигрываете? :)

Comment: @gil9red проигрываю не я, а плеер, возможно он их сам парсит как надо

Comment: Хорошо раз есть плеер, а нельзя ли ему указать позицию проигрывания? Добавьте описание плеера, например какую библиотеку используете

Comment: @gil9red именно, что нельзя, это плеер в голосовой канал дискорда из [discord py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voice), там есть только play и pause, сейчас добавлю

Comment: @gil9red можно ли в итоге как-то реализовать перемещение?

Comment: `FFmpegPCMAudio(b.read(), pipe=True, options=f"-ss {start_point / 1000}")`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, тогда и BytesIO не обязательно использовать?

Comment: Необязательно, у вас в аргументах `before_options` и `options` доступна вся мощь ffmpeg

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо

Comment: @andreymal, пожалуйста, оформите как ответ :)

Comment: @gil9red мне уже больше года как лень

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, оформите, пожалуйста, ответ и после примите его :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Позицию надо устанавливать как опцию к CLI-инструментарию `ffmpeg` в параметре `options` или `before_options`, когда создаем класс `FFmpegPCMAudio`

Пример:

```
start_position = 5000 # - пусть надо начать с 5 сек (5000 мсек)
FFmpegPCMAudio(b.read(), pipe=True, options=f"-ss {start_point / 1000}") # - для BytesIO

FFmpegPCMAudio('my_song.mp3', options=f"-ss {start_point / 1000}")
```

Для больших файлов, конечно, подвисает, но не сильно

Comment: Для больших файлов можно попробовать вместо `options` использовать `before_options` (но mp3 странный формат и такое перемещение может иногда промахиваться)

Comment: @andreymal да, я before_options как раз и поставил, тоже долговато, приходится async ожидать